# Asp.Net Web Application Deploy multiple assemblies

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

I'm migrating a Asp.Net WebSite to Asp.Net WebApp. But, I would like to still generating multiple assemblies when publish the WebApp as the same my old WebSite. I did some research, tried to use VS 2012 Publish Tools specifying different kinds of options as Do not Merge, Do not Merge. Create a Separete assembly for each page and control, but the published Package still generating a single **Assembly**.

Could you give me some Tips? Im stuck with this problem for hours!

Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you still want all the assemblies? Having only 1 assembly for your entire web app makes a lot stuff, including deployment, much easier.

Comment: This is a Big Project from a International Software Company, there's a lot of people working at the same time on this project. Some project changes and improving could be deployed wrongly to clients given that we have only a single assembly!

Comment: With the web site build, you get a ton of DLLs with random names. Don't you have to delete all of them and redeploy all your new ones when you do a new build? Otherwise you will most likely get conflicting classes.

Also, the single assembly is only for the web application, correct? sounds to me like you need to separate a lot of your logic into sub-projects. Each one of those will create it's own assembly.

Finally, what is your reasoning for converting from a web site to a web application?

Comment: @AaronS the entire project contain 4 layers for each module of the application, each module contains more than 50 project in each solution, theres more than 50 modules. Its a huge project! I would like only to split the WebApp project into multiple assemblies if possible to keep the same deployment routine for our clients and to avoid clients with wrong improvements or customization! Ty for taking your time! I need help here! Big trouble!

Comment: @AaronS We are converting to a web application because we are updating the old asp.net 2.0 to web 2.0, to MVC 4, then we could mantain both working side by side and improving it!

Comment: hmm, sounds like you may just need to keep it a web site then, and not try to upgrade it to a web application. The multiple assemblies in a web site are created because there isn't an underlying layer to keep track of all the other page classes, etc. A web application doesn't need to do this because the designer classes and the project file help keep track of all this.  One thing you could try, is to go back through and delete all the designer classes under each aspx page. I don't know what this will end up doing though. Good luck to you.

Comment: @AaronS Im doing this in a sandbox!! Theres no changes to the current source control yet! Thank you for you help! Hoping for someone that did It in the past! I must have the web app running side by side my MVC!! Thank you again!